# Como fazer um cálculo recursivo em um pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho um DataFrame com as operações de compra e vendas resultantes de um algorítimo de quant investing. Daí eu eu tentei fazer uma simulação com um valor inicial investido, para assim calcular o capital resultante após cada uma das operações.

[image: Pedaço do Dataframe]

Para isso, criei uma nova coluna chamada 'money' onde tento fazer um cálculo recursivo. Onde o valor atual para a coluna 'money' é o valor anterior multiplicado pela porcentagem do lucro/prejuizo da operação.

```py
ops_df['money'] = list( repeat(TOTAL_INVESTED, len(ops_df)) )
ops_df['money'] = (1 + ops_df.profit_perc.shift(1)) * ops_df.money.shift(1)
ops_df.head(10)
```

Porém, o cálculo recursivo esperado não ocorreu. Eu desconfio por conta de o lado direito da atribuição ser calculado por completo antes da atribuição.

[image: Recursão com problema]

Eu consegui resolver esse cálculo usando loop comum, porém fiquei com isso na cabeça. Deve existir uma maneira melhor e mais perfomática de fazer esse cálculo. Eu gostaria de saber se existe, como seria?

```
TOTAL_INVESTED = 1000
money = [TOTAL_INVESTED, ]

for i in range(1, len(ops_df)):
    curr_money = round( money[i-1] * (1 + ops_df.profit_perc.iloc[i]), 2 )
    money.append(curr_money)

ops_df['money'] = money
```

[image: Solução usando um loop comum]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como cada cálculo é um acúmulo de produtos, você pode usar [cumprod](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html):

```
import pandas as pd

TOTAL_INVESTED = 1000

ops_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"profit_perc": [-0.039548, 0.490518, 0.127511, -0.019439]})
money = (1 + ops_df.profit_perc.shift(-1)).cumprod() * TOTAL_INVESTED
ops_df["money"] = money.shift(1, fill_value=TOTAL_INVESTED).round(2)
print(ops_df)
```

Saída:

```
   profit_perc    money
0    -0.039548  1000.00
1     0.490518  1490.52
2     0.127511  1680.58
3    -0.019439  1647.91
```